# Error received when changing data for Mui-datatable : Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, mui-datatable

I get this error, if the format of my data for a MUIDatable changes.

Working format is:

```
const rows = [
    {   id:1,
        deviceId:1234567,
        deviceType:'xyz',
        deviceClass: "Conventional",
        __typename:"D1"}
    ];
```

but this one fails;

```
const rows = [
    {   id:1,
        deviceId:1234567,
        deviceType:'xyz',
        deviceClass:[
            { name: "conventional",
              __typename: "D1"},
        ],
        __typename:"Device"
    }
];
```

why would that be? I have other tables which have array objects in them, which work?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

By reading the documentation it doesn't seem like customizable rows are supported.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-datatables#customize-columns

Which prop  do you supply the `rows` array to? And how does the expected type look like?

Comment: i supply it to the rows prop. The first one does work, i.e. the datatable renders, but the 2nd one does not.

Comment: The type you are using does not fit the expected type on rows. So you need to inspect the expected type on rows and refactor the rows array accordingly. It's probably the deviceClass that does not expect a list of objects